# Sorting rows in postgres based on joined table - Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have the following situation

```
class Book
  has_many :book_publications
  has_many :publications, through: :book_publications
end

class BookPublication
  # book_id
  # publication_id
end

class Publication
  # date
end

Book1 | Publication1(2000)
Book1 | Publication2(2003)
Book2 | Publication3(2004)
Book2 | Publication4(1999)
```

I would like to sort the books based on the first publication date, not caring about the other dates.
So for ascending I would have Book2(1999), Book1(2000), and descending Book1(2000), Book2(1999).  The later years should not be counted in this query.
Basically i would need to find the first year of a publication for each book, attach it somehow to the query and order by that.
I also need to still be able to show the books that don't have publications. So i can't do a join to only get the rows that match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Book
  has_many :book_publications
  has_many :publications, through: :book_publications
  def self.order_by_publication_date
    left_joins(:publications)
      .group(:id)
      .order(Publication.arel_table[:date].minimum, :asc)
  end
end
```

If you want the date in the result set you can select it:

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :book_publications
  has_many :publications, through: :book_publications

  def self.order_by_publication_date
    left_joins(:publications)
      .select(
        arel_table[Arel.star],
        Publication.arel_table[:date].minimum.as('publication_date')
      )
      .group(:id)
      .order(:publication_date, :asc)
  end
end
```